# OpenCV.framewok on iPhone

Tags: ios, opencv, frameworks

Using this sources https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone
When I am trying to import  I have an error in opencv2/stitchin/warpers.hpp  "#include "detail/warpers.hpp" file not found"...
Who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. But when I created a new folder named "detail" within the stitching folder, it fixed the issue.. You will have to edit certain header files in opencv to reflect this change.